# LSSVM: the estimation function in the case of multiclass classification task

Tags: svm, least-squares

A version extended  from the SVM is the LSSVM (least square support vector machine) [lssvm wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_squares_support_vector_machine). The y(x) is like in SVM it gives us the sign y(x)= sign(alpha* k(.,.)* y + b) in other words the sign of " alpha* k(.,.)* y + b"=**Q** which is +1 or -1  I guess I missed somthing does this means that it gives me the sign of the **Q** (since this Q is number and could be positive or negative is not it if positive it would be affected to class +1 otherwise -1 ? am I correct!  suppose now that we deal with multiclass please see the figure I'd joined I would have for example for an object of the first class [-1  1] see the first columns of the matrix in this case what the " sign(alpha* k(.,.)* y + b)" would give me !! there is no +1 or -1 it is a couple ! How to interpret this please ! [image: here is how to do on lssvm for multiclasss]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For multiclass problems and SVM, you have to run all possible pairwise comparisons of 2-class problems.  So, for example, during the class 2 to class 4 comparison use +1 for objects in class 2 and -1 for objects in class 4.  (there would be no comparison needed for class 4 vs class 2).

Let $\Omega (\omega=1,2,\ldots,\Omega)$ be the number of classes.   Assume classes $l$ and $m$ are the two classes being compared, the decision function for test object $\bf{x}$ for this comparison is 
\begin{equation}
D_{lm}({\bf x})=\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i y_i {\bf x}_i^T{\bf x} + b_{lm},
\end{equation}
where $y_i$ and ${\bf x}_i$ are for all the training objects.   Next, run all comparisons of classes $l$ and $m$ $(l<m)$.  Once $D_{lm}$ is obtained for the comparisons for test object $\bf x$, the assignment of test object $\bf x$ 
to class $l$ is
\begin{equation}
D_{l}({\bf x})=\underset{m \neq l, m=1}{\sum^\Omega} {\rm sign}(D_{lm}({\bf x})).
\end{equation}

For test object $\bf x$, there will be a value of $D_{l}$ for each class, and the greatest one is the class that object $\bf x$ is assigned to, which in functional form looks like
\begin{equation}
D_{l}({\bf x}\rightsquigarrow \omega)=\underset{l=1,2,\ldots,\Omega}{\arg \max}\{ D_l({\bf x}) \}.
\end{equation}

During run-time when comparing class $l$ vs $m$, you just don't use the data for the other classes.  The $D_{lm}(\bf x)$ is like the predicted value of the test object.  A common approach is to assign $\bf x$ to class $l$ if $D_{lm}<0$ and class $m$ if $D_{lm}>0$.  However, you simply only need a $D_{lm}(\bf x)$ for each test object for all possible class comparisons, i.e., $D_{12}(\bf x)$, $D_{13}(\bf x)$, $D_{14}(\bf x)$, $D_{23}(\bf x)$, $D_{24}(\bf x)$, $D_{34}(\bf x)$ -- and you only use training and test objects from true classes $l$ and $m$ when obtaining each $D_{lm}(\bf x)$ - because the trained SVM can only make predictions for the two classes of data it was trained with.  Then, using all the $D_{lm}(\bf x)$ values,  calculate $D_{l}(\bf x)$ for each class $(l=1,2,3,4)$, and the greatest value among $D_{1}(\bf x)$, $D_{2}(\bf x)$ , $D_{3}(\bf x)$  and $D_{4}(\bf x)$ is the predicted class.  These decision functions used for SVMLS are the same as those used in L2SVM.

SVMs offer many advantages over other classifiers, for example, they maximize generalization ability, avoid local maxima, and are robust to outliers.  However, their disadvantages are that they do not extend easily to multiclass problems, can require long training times when quadratic programming is used, and are sensitive to model parameters the same way artificial neural networks are sensitive to the number of hidden layers and number of nodes at each hidden layer.

I actually don't like SVMs, and would never use them first. Rather, I would use linear regression [inputs $y_i=-1,+1$, with $D_{lm}({\bf x})=\beta_0 + \mathbf{x}^T\boldsymbol{\beta}$], kNN, NBC, LDA to first assess linear separability, then SVM and ANNs if the classes were not linear separable.

Comment: thank you for your time and consideration, related to "can require long training times when quadratic programming is used" what causes this! compared to lssvm we have a linear equations set that is way they said that is speedier, why the resolution of linear equation set is more simple ( speedy) than a QP !

Comment: That statement is more for the L2SVMs, which most analysts use, not the LSSVM.  LSSVM are faster since they avoid QP.  However, LSSVMs use equality constraints instead of inequality like L2SVMs, so they are vulnerable to outliers (see Suykens and Vandewalle, Neural Processing Letters, 9(3):293-300; 1999).

Comment: please can you explain more this part "For test object x, there will be a value of Dl for each class, and the greatest one is the class that object xx is assigned to, which in functional form looks like..+ the equation of arg max!" and intuitevely what the Dlm (x) is exactly (an example I see each term but what is exactly the whole of it I dont understand let s take an example suppose I have bought 3 things each of which is about 500 .  1500 is the total price I would like to understand the Dlm (x) is what exactly :)

Comment: The $D_{lm}(\bf x)$ is like the predicted value of the test object.  A common approach is to assign $\bf x$ to class $l$ if $D_{lm}<0$ and class $m$ if $D_{lm}>0$.   (this is exactly what is used in SVM).

Comment: see expanded discussion of $D_{lm}(\bf x)$ after the last equation.

Comment: thank you it is very helpfull :) I am gratefull thank you